# How to use super to refer to method(variable) of Parent class not method(function)

Tags: python-3.x

How do i use the super method to refer to the BMW/MERC/MAZDA stock in the Cars Parent class ? Why doesnt my stock reference code work, it just returns the value of none. It works for the **init** function and also stock check but just not when i want to call the method that is a written as a variable in the main parent class

Python Code

```
class Cars(object):
    def __init__(self,name,brand,color):
        self.name=name.lower()
        self.brand=brand.lower()
        self.color=color.lower()
    BMWStock = {"black":97,"white":85,"blue":64,"red":76}
    MERCStock= {"black":100,"white":77,"blue":84,"red":66}
    MAZDAStock={"black":65,"white":76,"blue":43,"red":54}
    def stock_check(self):
        if self.brand  == "bmw":
            if self.color not in self.BMWStock:
                print ("This colour scheme for this car is unavailable at the moment, sorry.")
            else:
                for k,v in self.BMWStock.items():
                    if self.color == k:
                        print (str(v) + " models of the car is still available")
        elif self.brand  == "merc":
            if self.color not in self.MERCStock:
                print ("This colour scheme for this car is unavailable at the moment, sorry.")
            else:
                for k,v in self.MERCStock.items():
                    if self.color == k:
                        print (str(v) + " models of the car is still available")
        elif self.brand  == "mazda":
            if self.color not in self.MAZDAStock:
                print ("This colour scheme for this car is unavailable at the moment, sorry.")
            else:
                for k,v in self.MAZDAStock.items():
                    if self.color == k:
                        print (str(v) + " models of the car is still available")

class ToyCars(Cars):
    def __init__(self,name,brand,color):
        super().__init__(name,brand,color)
    BMWStock = {"black":37,"white":25,"blue":24,"red":16}
    MERCStock= {"black":40,"white":37,"blue":14,"red":26}
    MAZDAStock={"black":15,"white":26,"blue":33,"red":24}
    def stock_check(self):
        super().stock_check()
    def stock_refer(self):
        super().BMWStock



cars1=Cars("Bryan","MAZDA","white")
small_cars_1=ToyCars("bryan","merc","blue")
print (small_cars_1.stock_refer())
```